# CRUD com AngularJS e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, http, crud

Boa noite!

Tenho o seguinte:

```
var carregarUsuario = function () {
    $http.get("buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno.data);
        $scope.usuarios = retorno.data;
    });
};
carregarUsuario();
```

E o PHP

```
    error_reporting(0);
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "angulardb";
    $host = "localhost";
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Erro: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM users");

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $return = array();

        while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
            array_push($return, $dados);
        }

        echo json_encode($return);
```

Nenhum dados está sendo exibido na pagina, ou no console. O que pode ser?

**EDIT**

Quando coloco um `print_r` no meu código PHP, logo após o `while` eu tenho:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [id] => 2
            [1] => João Silva
            [nome] => João Silva
            [2] => joao.silva@angular.com
            [email] => joao.silva@angular.com
            [3] => 123456
            [pass] => 123456
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [id] => 3
            [1] => Mario de Almeida
            [nome] => Mario de Almeida
            [2] => mario.almeida@angular.com
            [email] => mario.almeida@angular.com
            [3] => 123456
            [pass] => 123456
        )

)
```

Comment: Olha em seu console de está retornamdo algum erro.

Comment: O seu console não mostra absolutamente nada? E se você usar somente `console.log(retorno)` ?

Comment: @ViniciusSilva o console está em branco

Comment: @CelsomTrindade usando apenas o retorno, é exibido o seguinte:      Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: @LucasTorres então certifique-se de que o php está processando os dados corretamente, utilize alguns 'print_r' para ver quais sao os retornos. Pode ser problema no php na geracao dos dados.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, após o array_push, ainda dentro do bloco while, acrescentei print_r($return); e ele me retorna os dados:                                                              Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => João SIlva [nome] => João SIlva [2] => joao.silva@angular.com [email] => joao.silva@angular.com [3] => 123456 [pass] => 123456 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => João SIlva [nome] => João SIlva [2] => joao.silva@angular.com [email] => joao.silva@angular.com [3] => 123456 [pass] => 123456 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [id] =>...etc

Comment: 1- Abra o seu chrome, 2 - habilite ferramentas de desenvolvedor 3 - Vá na aba networking. 4, Olha o que ta vindo de response no seu php, veja se é um JSON válido ou se está vindo algum Erro 500, etc... 
Basicamente seu problema está no retorno do AJAX. Sugiro criar uma função de `catch`do erro: `$http.get("buscar.php").then(funcao sucesso, funcao catcherro)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido alterando o colation do banco de dados para UTF8

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a url completa do recurso e exibir no console a variável retorno.

```js
var carregarUsuario = function () {
    $http.get("http://localhost/buscar.php").then(function (retorno){
        console.log(retorno);
        $scope.usuarios = retorno;
    });
};
carregarUsuario();
```